# Search on Core data backed UITable issue?

Tags: search, uitableview, core-data

Not sure if this is the right place (I am sure someone will let me know if it is not)  I have a iPhone application that has a UITableview that is backed by core data.  I want to perform a reducing search so that only the items starting with the characters entered into the search bar are shown.  This is normally done with the delegate - (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText no problem.  I am a little confused as I am new to Core Data how to do this.  One of the big problems as I see it is going to be updating the interface to let it know what to present.  I assume an alternative NSFetchedResultsController needs to be sent to the UITableView is that correct?

So here are my issues:
1) I assume I need to create a  NSFetchedResultsController with only the correct items in it then tell the UITableView to use this as the dataSource and reload the table? 
2) is there a better way than executing a full sorted fetch and removing those objects that do not conform.  ie is there a way of doing a select where type fetch?

Thanks in advance and sorry if this is a dumb question.

Regards
Damien

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4481896/810661)

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, you will need a new NSFetchedResultsController.
2. You should use a NSPredicate in your new NSFetchRequest to filter by your search text.

For example, if your managed objects have a field "name" that should be filtered:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K beginswith[c] %@", @"name", searchText];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:pred];
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a slightly different solution: instead of relying on a different NSFetchedResultsController, I created a NSMutableArray (filteredListContent) in my table view controller, used to store the temporary data, as inspired by [Apple sample code](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/TableSearch/) and [Mugunth Kumar's tutorial](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-uisearchdisplaycontroller-with-nspredicate/).

In tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:, returning the appropriate data-source array:

```
if(receivedTableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView){
        Objects* object = [self.filteredListContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = object.name;
    } else {
        Objects* object = [self.unfilteredListContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = object.name;
    }
```

As in Apple's sample code, add pretty much the same method in other methods, such as

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)receivedTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if(receivedTableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView){
       return [self.filteredListContent count];
    }

    return [self.unfilteredListContent count];
}
```

As well as in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:...
Then conformed to UISearchDisplayDelegate protocol and added the following methods:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText
{

    if (!self.filteredListContent) {
        self.filteredListContent = self.filteredListContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    [self.filteredListContent removeAllObjects];


    for (Objects *object in [self.coreDataStuffVariable.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects])
    {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                                  @"(SELF contains[cd] %@)", searchText];

        NSString * elementTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", object.name];

        [elementTitle compare:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if([predicate evaluateWithObject:elementTitle])
        {
            [self.filteredListContent addObject:password];
        }
    }
}



- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller 
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString];
    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}
```

Pretty simple.  I guess it can end up badly if the core data objects are reloaded during a search, but well... if you can sleep knowing that then it may be a good solution!

Comment: I used this solution first (which is extensively used over the Web), but then felt like the point of using Core Data is not to put the search results in an array.