# Search as you type for large Core-Data data set

Tags: ios, search, core-data

I have a large core-data data set and i want to add search support. Currently i'm using fetched results controller to show the data in a uitableview. I'm planning on using UISearchDisplayController. Now i have two options:

1. Create a new fetched results controller for searched data
2. Use an array to show the filtered data

Which approach is more appropriate/recommended (particularly for search-as-you-type)? Is there any book or tutorial that addresses how to implement the suggested solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In several projects I went with the "new fetched results controller" option because the data that I was filtering possibly could eat up all of the ram in the older iPhones.  The FRC can handle low memory issues.  [This stackoverflow answer might be helpful to you if you go ith this option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471289/how-to-filter-nsfetchedresultscontroller-coredata-with-uisearchdisplaycontrolle/4481896#4481896)

Is your data small enough to fit within the usable ram of the lowest common denominator (1st generation iPhone)? If so then just filter in memory using a NSArray.  Performance wise, this would be faster than using the FRC.

Comment: I've done exactly that - used second fetched results controller. I've yet to test how good or bad it works with my original data-set. What's the largest data-set you've used with this search approach? I'm targeting first generation iPad in my case.

Comment: ~5000 entities but the biggest problem for performance would be what your searching predicate looks like (mine has a bunch of string compares and SUBQUERYs so it can be slow at times).

Answer (score 1):

Is the data constantly being written to? I had a set of 1,200 records to search through via a 'contains' search. What I did was on app launch have an object that contains all the data sets based on the coredata store. If the data gets updated during app use - it re-builds the sets.

Then when I get to the searching table view I search through the pre-loaded data. Doing a fetch each time caused too much lag - even with well written predicates and fetched results controller. I found it far faster to do it manually as I could create subsets of the data for faster searching.

Hope this helps makes your decision.

Cheers,

Michael

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by creating subset of data? I'm working with iOS, and i don't have the luxury of loading the complete data-set in-to memory. fetched results controller is my best bet!