# How to reduce the size of the table view that is getting displayed when using search display controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am using searchdisplaycontroller to display the search bar and the table that displays the search results. i need to modify the frame of the table view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure I understand your question.  However, when using the SearchDisplayController, the best way to perform the search that I have found is in the answer to the following question...

[How to filter NSFetchedResultsController (CoreData) with UISearchDisplayController/UISearchBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471289/how-to-filter-nsfetchedresultscontroller-coredata-with-uisearchdisplaycontrolle)

If this isn't what you are looking for, perhaps you can elaborate a bit more on what you are trying to accomplish.

To access the tableView used by the searchDisplayController, try this:

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView
```

Comment: i have used searchdisplaycontroller which shows tableview by default. i have to modify the size of the table view displayed. But i cannot find the reference to the tableview that the searchdisplaycontroller uses.

Comment: If you are trying access the tableview for the searchDisplayController, use the call listed above.  Really, if you are new to searchDisplayController as I was, really go through the code in that other answer.  It helps tremendously!

Comment: i want to modify the frame of the tableview. in the searchdisplaycontroller the table is only readable. i have tried using - (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didLoadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView; this delegate but this gets called only after the table is loaded. i got to change the frame of the table before it is getting loaded.

Comment: okay i got it working. i have to use the proper delegate. i used -(void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView and it worked. thanks