# Using Search bar with Core Data

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data, uisearchbar

I have tried various methods and this is the closest I have gotten, but the updating of the table makes all the entries off screen blank, and when I scroll, they all blank out. I am still new and am not entirely sure about implementing a search on core data tableview at all.

If I don't nil things out it dies here:

UPDATE: this is what I am trying now, and I am getting the same crash:
**`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'no section at index 1'`**

```
`Recipe *recipe = (Recipe *)[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];` **`Thread 1 received signal SIGABRT`**


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark search bar methods
- (void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSLog(@"searched");
    fetchedResultsController = nil;       
    //============
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Recipe" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    if (searchBar.text !=nil) {
        NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[cd] %@", searchBar.text];
        [fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    } else {
        NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"All"];
        [fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    }

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"state" ascending:YES];// was name
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor,sortDescriptor2, nil];// was 2

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"state" cacheName:@"Root"];//@"state"
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [fetchRequest release];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptor2 release];
    [sortDescriptors release];
    //==============

    // dismiss the search keyboard
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];

    // reload the table view
    //[self.tableView reloadData];

}


- (void)configureCell:(RecipeTableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Configure the cell //DIES HERE
    Recipe *recipe = (Recipe *)[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.recipe = recipe;
}
```

In other conditions, it dies when I try  to move the table up or down.

Thanks for any guidance or help with understanding and solving this issue!

Rob

tableViewController.m

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (fetchedResultsController == nil) {
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Recipe" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

        // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"state" ascending:YES];// was name
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];

        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor,sortDescriptor2, nil];// was 2

        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

        // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
        NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"state" cacheName:@"Root"];//@"state"
        aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
        self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

        [aFetchedResultsController release];
        [fetchRequest release];
        [sortDescriptor release];
        [sortDescriptor2 release];
        [sortDescriptors release];
    }
    return fetchedResultsController;
} 

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;

    self.searchBar.text=@"";

    [self.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    //self.tableView.allowsSelection = YES;
    //self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
}
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    // added 2 below
    //self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil;
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
    [self.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
    //self.tableView.allowsSelection = NO;
    //self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    // added 2 below
    //self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil;
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
    NSLog(@"fetchObjects");
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Recipe" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    //NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"state" ascending:YES];// was name
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];

    //NSLog(@"NSInteger value :%@", sortDescriptor);
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor2, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // perform query
    NSString *query = self.searchBar.text;
    if (query && query.length) fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@", query];


    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"state" cacheName:@"Root"];//@"state"
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [fetchRequest release];
    //[sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptor2 release];
    [sortDescriptors release];
    //[self.tableView reloadData];
}   

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    // The fetch controller is about to start sending change notifications, so prepare the table view for updates.
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you don't ever actually perform the fetch request. From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> After creating an instance, you invoke performFetch: to actually
>   execute the fetch.

Comment: as in: `NSError *error;
BOOL success = [fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];`?

Comment: Yeah. If you don't do that you will not get any results.

Comment: whether I perform the search or not, the app crashes on configure cell... thanks for the performFetch tip! .. still learning, fun but frustrating.

Comment: What does it say when it crashes?

Comment: And are you using a custom UITableViewCell that has a recipe property?

Comment: the cell uses fields from core data **Recipe**, I am using that data to populate the cell with images and text. as far as the error I didnt record it unfortunately. but it died on **configure cell**

Comment: I marked the answer as right because it was one part of a few things i was missing, but it got me on the right track, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a UISearchDisplayController? if you are you end up with two tables: one that displays your normal stuff  and the other related to the search.  You have to treat the tables separately.

There is a writeup of all the code you need to implement searching on tables at [How to filter NSFetchedResultsController (CoreData) with UISearchDisplayController/UISearchBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471289/how-to-filter-nsfetchedresultscontroller-coredata-with-uisearchdisplaycontroll/4481896#4481896)

Comment: I reread that several times, but I still dont know how @interface BlahViewController ()
ATproperty (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
ATproperty (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *searchFetchedResultsController;
ATproperty (nonatomic, retain) UISearchDisplayController *mySearchDisplayController;
ATend get implemented

Comment: they are synthesized and the getters are spelled out in the link's answer.