# can not initWithFrame uisearchbar

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2, uisearchbar

i was having problem while followed Brent Priddy's answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471289/how-to-filter-nsfetchedresultscontroller-coredata-with-uisearchdisplaycontroll)

it looks everyone ok with the code, but i got exc_bad_access rite on the uisearchbar initialization code, here it is:
[image]
and there was warning: Unable to restore previously selected frame. in the console
anyone know what is wrong here?

update my post:
the actuall error when i put this code into my implementation file:

```
    (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller 
    {
        UITableView *tableView = controller == self.fetchedResultsController ? self.tableView : self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView;
        [tableView beginUpdates];
    }

(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller 
  didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex 
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type 
{
    UITableView *tableView = controller == self.fetchedResultsController ? self.tableView : self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView;

    switch(type) 
    {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller 
   didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)theIndexPath 
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath 
{
    UITableView *tableView = controller == self.fetchedResultsController ? self.tableView : self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView;

    switch(type) 
    {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:theIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self fetchedResultsController:controller configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:theIndexPath] atIndexPath:theIndexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:theIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

(void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller 
{
    UITableView *tableView = controller == self.fetchedResultsController ? self.tableView : self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView;
    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

i hope someone can help me.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using only `tableview`, not `self.tableview`.

Comment: it said "use of undeclare identifier "tableView" if i using tableview without self.

Comment: Then try with hard coded width. If its working then may be issue is in tableview.

Comment: its still show the same error, here it was --> UISearchBar *searchBar = [[[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 0)] autorelease]; any suggestion?

Comment: the actual error is there is invite loop on creating(init) uisearchbar, do u know why?