# When should I use deleteCacheWithName with fetchedResultsController?

Tags: ios, uitableview, caching, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

When using core data + table views in combination with SearchDisplayController the predicate for the fetchedResultsController is changed such that only the subset of results confirming to the string in the search display are fetched.

The function shouldReloadDisplayForSearchString is called several times when the user types a search string. A common strategy seems to be to simply overwrite the current predicate for the fetched ResultsController with a new one. Apple suggests to invoke deleteCacheWithName when the search predicate is changed.

For me it seems to be a bit brutal to delete the cache every time. Is this the best practice for this case? Are there other strategies, such as instantiating a temporal fetchedResultsController for the search?

Thanks for Help!

Answer (score 1):

I think that, as you said, it is a bit brutal and you'd better using a different request for search controller. I, for example, don't use a fetched results controller for search controller but a request to an array. While my fetched results controller is not modified.

Comment: This approach sounds legit. Is it easy to switch the data source of the table view from fetchedResultsController to array?

Comment: The simplest solution is to use the same tableViewController as datasource for tableView and for searchController.tableView. Then, in all datasource methods you can begin with: `if(tableView==self.tableView)` to check wich of both tableViews you are attending.

Comment: I think I will go for [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471289/how-to-filter-nsfetchedresultscontroller-coredata-with-uisearchdisplaycontroll?answertab=votes#tab-top). It uses 2 fetchedResultsController.