# Searching CoreData using NSFetchedResultsController and Search Display Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

This is probably a simple question but after a fair amount of searching around i'm still a little confused on the correct answer.

I have an app using Core Data and a UITableView populated by NSFetchedResultsController. I want to add a search bar to the top of the tableview and filter the data live in the tableview using Search Bar and Search Display Controller

What i want to know is what is the correct way of doing this?

Most examples i've seen modify the NSFetchRequest predicate each time the search term changes? This seem like it would add a lot of overhead with all the requests

The apple examples only seem to deal with searching tableview results based on arrays.

Should I create an array based on fetchedObjects and search on that array and put filtered results into another array.

Many Thanks in Advance
Matt

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471289/how-to-filter-nsfetchedresultscontroller-coredata-with-uisearchdisplaycontroll

Answer (score 0):

Do not optimize too early.

Change the predicate for the fetch request.  NSFetchResultsController is really good about minimizing access to CoreData.

Once you have it working, use instruments to isolate any performance issues.

If you search the array of objects yourself, you will have to fault every object into memory, and then search through them all.  Yes, you are still going to have to search them all, but let CoreData do it, because it is almost always much faster.

**EDIT**

The Stanford iTunes U course on iOS app development is a good option for free video instruction.  Ray Wenderleich has a good tutorial devoted to NSFetchedResultsController here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller

Comment: do you know of any good stackover answers or web tutorials covering a good implementation of NSFetchResultsController and searching?

Comment: thanks for the comment, i'm already a big fan of both of those resources but as far as I know they don't cover searching and NSFetchResultsController.

Comment: Take a look at Apple WWDC 12 session on core data

Comment: @NikitaPestrov which session were you looking at? 2010 or 2011 core data session? WWDC 12 hasn't happened yet, thanks.