# Can scope bar buttons be used to filter results without activating the keyboard of a UISearchBar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I display a UITableView with a search bar and scope bar buttons on load. When a user taps a scope bar button, the keyboard is displayed and the search bar gets focus (becomes first responder).

Is it possible to allow the use of the scope bar buttons to filter the table items without having the keyboard appear? The user could get the keyboard to appear by specifically tapping within the search text entry field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My solution in the end involved the use of two delegate methods and a state variable on the view controller.

On the view controller i added the property

```
NSNumber *scopeButtonPressedIndexNumber; 

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {  

  if (self.scopeButtonPressedIndexNumber != nil) {
    self.scopeButtonPressedIndexNumber = nil; //reset
    return NO;
  }
  else {
    return YES;  
  }

} 

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange:(NSInteger)selectedScope {
  self.scopeButtonPressedIndexNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:selectedScope];
}
```

In essence, I capture if the scope button is pressed, and I return NO in shouldBeginEditing if that is the case. In this way, I was able to prevent focus from going to the search bar.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. The implementation depends on how you set up your UITableView, but assuming you're using NSFetchedResultsControllers, you could do this:

1) Let's say you have 3 scope bar buttons; create 4 NSFRCs.

2) Create fetch requests for the first 3 NSFRCs, each with a predicate to select only the relevant scope for the corresponding scope bar button.

3) Use the final NSFRC for the search functionality. See Brent Piddy's post on [How to filter NSFetchedResultsController (CoreData) with UISearchDisplayController/UISearchBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471289/how-to-filter-nsfetchedresultscontroller-coredata-with-uisearchdisplaycontroll) for details on how to implement search if you've not already done so.

4) When the user taps a scope bar button, **do not** write any text into the search bar but rather just swap in the relevant NFC. Highlight the button (or consider using a UISegmentedControl) so the user can see what scope they're looking at.

5) When the user types text into the search bar, swap in the search bar NSFRC as detailed in Brent's post above. Remove any highlighting on the buttons or UISegmentedControl and leave the search bar on screen with the user's text so, again, they can see what scope they're looking at.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I don't think it addresses what I intended my main question to be. Namely, how to prevent focus from being taken by the search bar when tapping the scope buttons. I my testing, "not writing" any text was not adequate because focus was still taken by the search bar. I am providing an answer below to describe what I did. If you feel it is not correct, I would appreciate your feedback.