# Don't understand this syntax in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, syntax

In this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4481896/1486928

there is a line like this :

```
 UITableView *tableView = controller == self.fetchedResultsController ? self.tableView : self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView;
```

It's the first time I see all these symbols in the same line :/ (I'm a beginner).

Comment: Usually people use parenthesis around the condition to make it more readable :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the conditional operator. What it does is basically it returns one of two values based on its condition:

```
SomeType variable = condition ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse;
```

This can be interpreted as

```
SomeType variable;
if (condition) {
    variable = valueIfTrue;
} else {
    variable = valueIfFalse;
}
```

Here the condition is

```
controller == self.fetchedResultsController
```

so of the view controller is equal to `self.fetchedResultsController`, the tableView variable will be assigned to `self.tableView`, else it'll be assigned to `self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView`

Comment: Sorry I never learned C I started with objective-c with Aaron Hillegass book, he gives a quick crash course in C but didn't say anything about this "?". PS : je ne peux pas accepter ta réponse avant 4 min mais merci beaucoup :-)

Comment: @Clarisse You're welcome - de rien, je connais le limit de 4 minutes ;)

Answer (score 4):

`something ? foo : bar` is just a shorter version of

```
if(something) {
   foo
} else {
   bar 
}
```

It is called the ternary operator.

So your piece of code becomes:

```
UITableView *tableView;
if(controller == self.fetchedResultsController) {
    tableView = self.tableView;
} else {
    tableView = self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView;
}
```

Comment: Except that that's not legal obj-c.

Comment: You can not write the if statement like that.

Comment: This is different from the original since after the if, tableView is out of scope.

Comment: Blargh, long time no Objective-C coding. Fixed again.

Answer (score 2):

It means that if `controller` is equal to `self.fetchedResultsController`, then

set 
`tableView = self.tableView`, otherwise

set `tableView = self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView`

You could represent it as

```
UITableView *tableView;
 if (controller == self.fetchedResultsController)
     tableview = self.tableView;
 else
     tableview = self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView;
```

Comment: Except that it doesn't set *tableView but tableView itself.

Comment: First, thank you all for answering that quickly I mean really less than a minutes you're great, but could you decide which answer is the best for me ? Thank you !

Comment: @H2CO3 : Oops! That was a typo in haste. Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Comment: @Clarisse : You are the one who can decide which is the best! :)

Answer (score 1):

This shows you the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a).

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a).

Written out longhand:

```
 UITableView *tableView;
 if (controller == self.fetchedResultsController)
     tableview = self.tableView;
 else
     tableview = self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView;
```