# UISearchDisplayController, UITableView and Core Data

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am quite new at iOS programming.
I have implemented a UITableView that is populated with CoreData using a NSFetchedResultsController. This part works very well. I have then added a UISearchDisplayController to be able to search the table. The search itself works fine but it seems I am leaking my CoreData objects when I reload the view. The app does not crash but Instrument reports object being leaked in the CoreData framework every time I perform a search or I dismiss the SearchView.

I have implemented the search function like this:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText
                             scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    if (searchText && searchText.length) {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains %@", searchText];
        [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    }

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        // Handle error
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        exit(-1);  // Fail
    }

}
```

When I dismiss the SearchBar I do:

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    NSLog(@"searchBarTextDidEndEditing: Reset fetchedResultsController predicate" );
    self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@",error,[error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
}
```

Can anyone see what am I doing wrong?

Thanks
Cam

Update: I followed this post [How to filter NSFetchedResultsController (CoreData) with UISearchDisplayController/UISearchBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471289/how-to-filter-nsfetchedresultscontroller-coredata-with-uisearchdisplaycontroll) and implemented the getter in the same way but I am still leaking core data objects when I "type" some letters in the search bar so it seems the problem is when I am fetching new data not dismissing the view.

The code looks like:

1) When I type in the search bar I set to nil self.searchBarFetchedResultsController

```
(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    self.searchBarFetchedResultsController.delegate = nil;
    self.searchBarFetchedResultsController = nil;
}
```

2) When the getter is called again I allocate a new FRC as per the example.

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)searchBarFetchedResultsController
{
    if (_searchBarFetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return _searchBarFetchedResultsController;
    }
    _searchBarFetchedResultsController = [self newFetchedResultsControllerWithSearch:self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text];
return _searchBarFetchedResultsController;
}


- (NSFetchedResultsController *)newFetchedResultsControllerWithSearch:(NSString *)searchString
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Beers"];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains %@", searchString];
    if(searchString.length)
    {
        [request setPredicate:predicate];
    }
    [request setFetchBatchSize:20];
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                                                managedObjectContext:self.beerDB2.managedObjectContext
                                                                                                  sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                                           cacheName:nil];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
   NSError *error = nil;
    if (![aFetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
    }
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return aFetchedResultsController;
}
```

Then when I am accessing the FRC from the delegates methods I am using this method to get the correct one.

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsControllerForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

  return tableView == self.favTab ? self.fetchedResultsController : self.searchBarFetchedResultsController;

}
```

All works perfectly except that the Inspector tells me I am leaking hundreds of core data objects :( And what makes me crazy is that not all the time I am leaking them. For some search will work fine then it will start leak. At that point any subsequent search will trigger a leak.

Comment: Do you have a custom getter for fetchedResultsController? If so, what's that code look like?

Comment: Hi Hunter,I think I have an initial idea of the issue. I am using a single FRC for both TableViews. I did not understood at the beginning they were separate (the initial one and the one for the searchBar). Tonight I will try to implement it with two FRC and see if it works. If not I will post more details! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On 'viewdidload', fetch all details in an globally declared array ... and in search function, filter the array using 'NSPredicate'