# DidselectRowatindex doesnt calling after search in ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

Hi I have several UITableViews. I want to add search bars for each Tables.

So I added UISearchbars two of tables.

I only added `searchbars`, didnt add `UISearchbarDisplaycontroller`.

When user type something on the search bar and press the searchbutton in the keyboard, search result getting to another `NSMutableArray` and assign to my original array. Then reload the `UITableView`

According to my code its working. when I type something and press the search button, my table reload with new data. But now the problem is I cannot click any cell. seems like its not calling to `didselectRowatIndex` method. But buttons which are inside cells still I can click properly. Only the cell click event is not calling.

What should be the reason for this. Please help me

Thanks

**EDIT**

```
.h
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController<UITabBarDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,FPPopoverControllerDelegate,AVAudioPlayerDelegate,UISearchBarDelegate>

ViewDidload

searchbarAllusers.delegate=self;
searchbarAllusers.showsCancelButton = YES;
searchbarArtists.delegate=self;
searchbarArtists.showsCancelButton=YES;

Search delegates

-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar3
{
    if (searchBar3.text.length==0) {
        isSearch=NO;
    }
    else
    {
        isSearch=YES;
        if (searchBar3.tag==1) {
            [self filterListForSearchText:searchBar3.text :@"USR"];
        }

        else if (searchBar3.tag==2)
        {
            [self filterListForSearchText:searchBar3.text :@"ARTIST"];
        }

        [searchBar3 resignFirstResponder];
    }
}

-(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar2
{
    [searchBar2 resignFirstResponder];
    isSearch=NO;

    if (searchBar2.tag==1) 
    {
            tblAddFriends.delegate=self;
            searchbarAllusers.delegate=self;
            tblAddFriends.allowsSelection=YES;
        [tblAddFriends reloadData];
    }
    else if (searchBar2.tag==2)
    {
        arrArtistList=artistTemparray;
        tblArtists.delegate=self;
        searchbarArtists.delegate=self;
        tblArtists.allowsSelection=YES;
        [tblArtists reloadData];
    }   
}  
- (void)filterListForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText : (NSString *)status
{
    [searchResult removeAllObjects];
    if([status isEqualToString:@"USR"])
    {
        searchResult=[ws SearchItems:searchText :status];
        [tblAddFriends reloadData];
    }
    else if([status isEqualToString:@"ARTIST"])
    {
        searchResult=[ws SearchItems:searchText :status];
        [tblArtists reloadData];
    }
}
```

Comment: May be instead of `didselectRowatIndex` method you have `didDeselectRowatIndex`.

Comment: Possible duplicate (recreation) of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275481/uitableview-didselect-method-is-not-caling-after-search-something-using-search-b

Comment: no before I add the searchbar didselect method worked perfectly

Comment: have you checked wether your table view's delegate is still set properly after you added the search bar?

Comment: Also, why are't you using UISearchDisplayController? BTW, I really recommend this answer on SO regarding search in a UITableView: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4481896/921573