# Trouble with search in NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: objective-c, search, nspredicate, xmppframework, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using `NSFetchedResultsController` to store a custom objects of type: `XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject`. I need to search my fetchedResultsController for a match between field `displayName` of `XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject` and search text.
I gain access to this field by:

```
XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user = [[self fetchedResultsController] fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:i];
```

and then:

```
 user.displayName;
```

where `i` is number of object in `NSFetchedResultsController`.

How can I make predicate with format to compare `user.displayName;` and `searchText`?

My search method is:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{

if ([searchText length] == 0) {
    fetchedResultsController = nil;
}
else {
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"XXX contains[cd] %@", searchText]; 
    [[fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] setPredicate:predicate];
    [[fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] setFetchLimit:50];
}

NSError *error;
if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
}

[mainTableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18580245/1236726) solution. It is example of how to make compound predicate for search by `Core Data` fetch results.