# UISearchDisplayController is showing results in a popover instead of filtering my UITableView

Tags: uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uipopover

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4481896/176248) great approach to filter the entries my UITableView in my iPad app. However the UISearchDisplayController creates a UISearchResultsTableView and shows it in a popover. What's wrong here? Has it to do with iOS7?

My table view:

[image]

After entering a search string:

[image]