# Passing data between table views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, uisearchbar

I've got a problem, I created a `UITableView` using `CoreData` to pass data between the views (`UITableView` to `DetailView` of a `row`) I used this method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"UpdateData"]) {
        NSManagedObject *selectedDevice = [self.datas objectAtIndex:
                                 [[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
        DetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.datas = selectedDevice;

     }
}
```

and everything works fine. But later I added a `UISearchBar` that didn't work with `NSManagedObject` so i created another `NSMutableArray` where I saved all the `NSStrings` composing the `cell.textLabel.text`and it works. But now I need to modify the `prepareForSegue` in order to perform a `segue` whenever I select a row from the SearchBar tableView.

The problem is that to perform this kind of `segue` connecting with the `CoreData` I need to use the `NSManagedObject`, so my question is:
How can i get the `indexPath.row` from the `UISearchBar` inside my `UITableView` and make it correspond to the right `indexPath.row` of my `self.data` (that is the array I used to perform the normal `segue` in the `UITableView`, see code) ? 
I thought I could compare the strings of the cell (cell.textLabel.text) but

1. don't know how to do.
2. there could be a problem if there are 2 rows with same name I suppose.

any advice?

**EDIT:** I added the UISearchBar from the storyboard and this is the code i use to filter the main table view:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    [_searchDati removeAllObjects];
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", searchText];
    _searchDati = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[_tableData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate]];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}
```

Where `_searchDati` is the array i created for the UISearchBar and `_tableData` is the array i created to store the name of the cells from the NSManagedObject that contains the CoreDatas.

and i also added this

```
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didLoadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    [tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}

//Handle selection on searchBar
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"UpdateData" sender: self];
    }
}
```

The first because i used this and i need to register the class or gave me an error

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

and the second one to handle the selection of the UISearchBarTableView.

In here i load the tableView as i said before

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
       // see filter method
        cell.textLabel.text = [_searchDati objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    } else {
        NSString *string;
        NSManagedObject *data = [self.datas objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [data valueForKey:@"name"]];
        [cell.detailTextLabel setText:nil];
        cell.textLabel.text = string;

        //store the string to the tableView array
        [_tableData addObject:string];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

**EDIT#2:**

i Wrote this code

NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath2 = nil;

```
if ([self.searchDisplayController isActive]) {

    indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    for(int i = 0 ; i < _tableData.count ; i++){
        if([self.searchDati[indexPath.row] isEqualToString:_tableData[i]]){
            indexPath2 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:1];
        }
    }
    NSManagedObject *selectedDevice = [self.datas objectAtIndex:indexPath2.row];
    destViewController.datas = selectedDevice;
```

when i click on a row on the UISearchBar and it WORKS only for the first time! I make the search and click on the row and it goes to the right DetailView, but if i do it again it crashes giving me this error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'
```

i think the problem is that does not start from the indexPath.row == 0 but create a sort of pile after the first time.
Any suggestion? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If I understood correctly the problem, this question might help (the answer by Chris worked for me): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471289/how-to-filter-nsfetchedresultscontroller-coredata-with-uisearchdisplaycontroll/9512891#comment28141617_9512891

Comment: How is your search bar set up?  Are you using a search display controller?  Is it filtering your main tableview?

Comment: i've edited with the code for filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"UpdateData"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
NSManagedObject *selectedDevice = [self.datas objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        DetailViewController * destViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
destViewController.datas = selectedDevice;

     }
}
```

Comment: I had already tried this but it doesn't work because this way if i filter the names leaving only one (that is in row #1) when i click on that row it perform a segue to the #1 row of the main table view. Meaning i have 3 rows "one" "two" "three" i search for "three" and i click on it i will be directed to "one" DetailView because in the self.tableView it has the indexPath.row == 1.