# Unable to Interact with UISearchBar in a UITableView

Tags: uitableview, ios7, uisearchbar

### The Issue

I have a UIGestureRecognizer setup that on press to any of the UITableViewCell in my UITableView, it sets the UISearchBar active. Everything works. I can press on the cell and the UISearchBar animates as it would normally. I can enter letters, tap and hold on the UITextField and zoom in to a specific cursor position. I can hit cancel and everything goes back to their proper locations.

This is where the issue comes up. I scroll down a few cell (or until the UISearchBar is hidden under the UINavigationBar) and press the cell to activate the UISearchBar. Everything seems to animate to their proper location but when I try to tap and hold to zoom in to a proper cursor on the textfield nothing happens. I am also unable to hit the cancel button. The odd part is that if I do press on any part of the UISearchBar, it becomes the first responder.

### Things I have done

- I played around with the contentInset of the searchResultsTableView and see if that was blocking the UISearchBar.
- I played around with the frame of the searchResultsTableView and its superview to see if it is blocking the UISearchBar.
- I added the methods defined in the UISearchDisplayDelegate protocol and ensure that there were no views blocking said UISearchBar.

### Please help!

My goal is to be able to interact with the UISearchBar as it is intended. If you know of any other option I can please let me know!

Thank you in advance!!

## Update

I found the answer at [Programmatically activating UISearchBar blocks user interactions with it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19688500/798958)

There is a possibility of a timing issue when the UISearchBar is shown and when it becomes active so the solution is to delay activating it.

Answer (score 0):

So when you scroll down, the tableview is actually not referencing to the original cell as a result of the way iOS tries to reuse cells to conserve memory. The way to solve this is to say if(indexPath.row==0){cell.contentview addGesture...} in the cellForIndexPath function or use the didSelectAtIndexPath function to specify what happens when you click indexPath.row 0

Comment: I am adding the gesture in the cellForIndexPath. The issue I am having is with the UISearchBar not acting normal (can not hit the cancel button, can not tap-n-hold to zoom/move the cursor) when it is scrolled under the UINavigationBar.

Comment: oh ok, perhaps i misunderstood your question. So you have a searchBar embedded in a cell? and it's not working when you tap it inside the cell?

Comment: I wanted to add this image to my question to help would-be helpers but I do not have the right reputation yet it seems :( http://imgur.com/7YdpL1H The UISearchBar is embedded in the UITableView. I hope this helps and thank you!

Comment: So... Shinigami's updated question (basically his/her solution) worked for me. It seems like there is a timing issue when the UISearchBar is activated and becomes first responder. Thank you Nate for the response! http://stackoverflow.com/q/19688500/798958