# Autocomplete with Core Data and UISearchDisplayController in a TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, uisearchbar

I am implementing a `UISearchBar` in the `header` of a `TableView` and I want to manage the Results with `Core Data` and `NSFetchedResultsController`, giving also a custom look&feel to this Results Table. I have a `TableView` with: `Header`, it is the `UISearchBar`; 3 sections: First Section is the name of a Country, this country can be taken from  the Location or selecting it from the `UISearchResults TableView`. Second section is: What do you want, which has some rows, and the third section is a Filter with more options in its rows..

This `TableView` is a SidePanel (JASidePanel control) from CocoaControls.com.

Now, my problem is that I can not see the Results of the Core Data request in my searchResults Tableview.

I have followed this link [Filter NSFetchedResultController with Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471289/how-to-filter-nsfetchedresultscontroller-coredata-with-uisearchdisplaycontroll)

This log output shows 0;

```
 NSLog(@"Numbers of Sections = %i",
              [[aFetchedResultsController sections] count]);
```

This is the code I am using:

```
@interface WPFilterSidePanelViewController (){

    NSString        *savedSearchTerm_;
    NSInteger       savedScopeButtonIndex_;
    BOOL            searchWasActive_;

      NSFetchedResultsController *searchFetchedResultsController_;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *searchFetchedResultsController;


@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *savedSearchTerm;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger savedScopeButtonIndex;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL searchWasActive;
@end

#pragma mark - Search Display Delegate methods

#pragma mark Content Filtering
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSInteger)scope
{
    // update the filter, in this case just blow away the FRC and let lazy evaluation create another with the relevant search info
    self.searchFetchedResultsController.delegate = nil;
    self.searchFetchedResultsController = nil;
    // if you care about the scope save off the index to be used by the serchFetchedResultsController
    //self.savedScopeButtonIndex = scope;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Search Bar
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller willUnloadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
{
    // search is done so get rid of the search FRC and reclaim memory
    self.searchFetchedResultsController.delegate = nil;
    self.searchFetchedResultsController = nil;
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]];

    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}


- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar text]
                               scope:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]];

    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}


#pragma mark - NSFetchedResultsController Delegate methods
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    UITableView *searchTableView = self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView;
    [searchTableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    UITableView *searchTableView =  self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView;
    [searchTableView endUpdates];
}


- (NSFetchedResultsController *)newFetchedResultsControllerWithSearch:(NSString *)searchString
{

    NSLog(@"string search bar%@", searchString);

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:nil]];
    NSPredicate *filterPredicate = nil;//[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@",searchString ];

    /*
     Set up the fetched results controller.
     */
    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *callEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:kEntityStore inManagedObjectContext:mainContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:callEntity];

    NSMutableArray *predicateArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    if(searchString.length)
    {
        // your search predicate(s) are added to this array
        [predicateArray addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchString]];
        // finally add the filter predicate for this view
        if(filterPredicate)
        {
            filterPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:filterPredicate, [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicateArray], nil]];
        }
        else
        {
            filterPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicateArray];
        }
    }
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:filterPredicate];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];


    NSLog(@"%@", fetchRequest);
    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                                                managedObjectContext:mainContext
                                                                                                  sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                                           cacheName:nil];

    NSLog(@"Numbers of Rows = %i",
          [[[aFetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:0] numberOfObjects]);
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    NSLog(@"%@", aFetchedResultsController);
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![aFetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
    {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return aFetchedResultsController;
}


- (NSFetchedResultsController *)searchFetchedResultsController
{
    NSLog(@"SearchBar text :%@ ", self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text);

    searchFetchedResultsController_ = [self newFetchedResultsControllerWithSearch:self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text];
    return searchFetchedResultsController_ ;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
   [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
    [self creatingSearchBar];

    if (self.savedSearchTerm)
    {
        [self.searchDisplayController setActive:self.searchWasActive];
        [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setSelectedScopeButtonIndex:self.savedScopeButtonIndex];
        [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setText:savedSearchTerm];

        self.savedSearchTerm = nil;
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    self.searchWasActive = [self.searchDisplayController isActive];
    self.savedSearchTerm = [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar text];
    self.savedScopeButtonIndex = [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex];

    fetchedResultsController_.delegate = nil;
    fetchedResultsController_ = nil;
    searchFetchedResultsController_.delegate = nil;
    searchFetchedResultsController_ = nil;

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // save the state of the search UI so that it can be restored if the view is re-created
    self.searchWasActive = [self.searchDisplayController isActive];
    self.savedSearchTerm = [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar text];
    self.savedScopeButtonIndex = [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex];
}


-(void)creatingSearchBar
{
    searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 44.0)];
    searchBar.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);
    searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;

    self.searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
    self.searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing your table view `datasource` methods. Those should recreate your fetched results controller when calling `self.fetchedResultsController`. I assume you have forgotten them as you have chosen to post a lot of irrelevant code.

Also, in your code you set a predicate to `nil` and then check if it is nil later. Regardless you construct a compound predicate with an array of predicates that contain only one element. Both strategies are not very meaningful.

Comment: You mean datasource for my main TableView? or searchResults TableView. My Main TableView is working great and without fetchedResultContoller, because I don not need it. I have problems only with SearchResults. I did not show the code of the main tableview because I thought it was too much code

Comment: Having separate arrays for the table view datasource seems a bad idea. You should be using the fetched results controller. I am sure your problem is there. Maybe you want to delete most of your posted code and include the mechanism of your datasource arrays.

Comment: but I need one array of sections with an array in each section, because it is a tableview with different Filters. and I also need the SearchBar only for get Countries and if the user press in one country then I change the name of the First Section for the country name.. 
I thought I can have one different TableView with the Search Results over the SidePanel TableView.

Comment: Nothing in your remark is a good argument for duplicating data from the FRC. FRC is capable of all the things you mention while optimising for memory and performance.

Comment: No.. but i am not duplicating FRC, even though it is interesting what you say. I only use FRC for the list of Countries.