# UISearchDisplayController and CoreData 'no object at index 2 in section at index 0'

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios7, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm using CoreData to store some data (not big amounts). I've decided to add to my TVC (where the data is displayed) a `UISearchDisplayController` so users will be able to search by a text. To search in CD, I'm using second `NSFetchedResultsController`. The problem is that I'm getting the following error: `'no object at index 2 in section at index 0'`.

I've checked several things to resolve the problem:

- how many objects were fetched from db,
- what are the values given by `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`, `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`
- I've also checked that tableView passed to both methods is pointing to `self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView` what I believe is correct
- number of objects in `fetchedObjects` is the same as value returned by `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`
- I have only one section (`sectionNameKeyPath = nil` in fetch request)

I found several similar problems but nothing helped me. My implementation is based on [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4481896)

What am I doing wrong ? Where can be possibly a mistake ? Let me know if you need more information. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:

I've been working on it lately at night. When I returned to the code with fresh mind in the morning, I've realized several things.

**SOLUTION**

I've been using such a code:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
   didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    .
    .
    .
    UITableView *tableView = controller == self.fetchedResultsController ? self.tableView : self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

When I `self.fetchedResultsController = nil` at the beginning of searching, what lead to the error.

Also I've always used the same fetchedResultsController. The `[self fetchedResultsControllerForTableView:tableView]` (method from the code I'm linking above) fix the problem. Be sure that you are using appropriate fetchedResultsController ! And even if you are, check once again.

After this I should get my search results ... but I didn't.

Other thing was using `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`. Looks pretty OK but in the tableView in searchDisplayController I didn't have cells for a given identifier so I needed to dequeue them from `self.tableView`.

Now I have my search results.

If you don't have yours, this can also help:

```
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didLoadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    [tableView registerClass:[NewsCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:identifier];
}
```

Thank you to everyone who read about my problem and took a minute to think about solution.

Comment: You check the table view in all methods?

Comment: @Wain thank you for this question. Checking this again I found the problem lying right next to it.