# UITableViewController won't update with NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate + UISearchBarDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UITableViewController defined in the .h like this:

```
@interface PartsSearchViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
    NSMutableArray *parts;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
    Metadata *metadata;
}
```

and the .m like this:

```
@interface PartsSearchViewController () <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate>
```

When items are selected, it pushes w/standard segue to a detail view:

```
@interface PartSearchDetailViewController : UIViewController
```

Most of what I want the app to do seems to be working. There are several switches + fields in the detail view that, when changed, write to core data. If a user makes changes in the detail view, then returns to the table view (by hitting **< Search**), the changes to the object in the corresponding cell are rendering with the changes made as expected, **but only if no search has been implemented**.  If search has been implemented in the table, however, the changes on the filtered set of objects in the table don't display until after the user has "scrolled around" and forced the affected cells to redraw within the filtered set.

I have verified that the changes to the object data have definitely been made in Core Data. (Otherwise, the "scrolling around" bit wouldn't correct the cell content either.)

I have also verified that in either condition (search or no search implemented), my `viewWillAppear` is being called:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    CoreDataController *cdc = [[CoreDataController alloc] init];

    PartsPlant *thisPartsPlant = [cdc getLoadedPartsPlant];
    // A "part" is the object that's displayed in each cell.
    // "parts" is NSMutableArray of "part" objects.
    self.parts = thisPartsPlant.parts;

    UITableView *tv = (UITableView *)self.view;
    [tv reloadData];
}
```

When I step through the update of the cells, I can see that the correct data is being passed to render the cell, but the cell never renders.

I suspect I can't see the issue because I don't fully understand what's going on with `UISearchDisplayController` stuff. I modded an example from UseYourLoaf that fills an NSArray with filtered results when a search is implemented. My guess is somehow on the reload, I need to force the rerendering on this set instead of the contents of the `fetchedResultsController`?

Here is what the UISearchDisplayController calls when applying a search to the table view:

```
- (void)searchForText:(NSString *)searchText scope:(PartsSearchScope)scopeOption
{
    if (self.managedObjectContext)
    {
        NSString *predicateFormat = @"%K CONTAINS[cd] %@";
        NSString *searchAttribute = @"partName";

        if (scopeOption == searchScopePartNumber)
        {
            searchAttribute = @"partNumber";
        }

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateFormat, searchAttribute, searchText];
        [self.searchFetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

        NSError *error = nil;
        self.filteredList = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:self.searchFetchRequest error:&error];
        isFilterApplied = YES;
    }
}
```

Then, if `self.SearchDisplayController.isActive`, anywhere the table view would normally go for the `self.fetchedResultsController`, it goes for `self.filteredList` instead.

Sorry for the rambling - I'm a C/iOS newbie. Any kind of help is appreciated. I can provide more code - just not sure what's pertinent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, it is best to have two fetched results controllers, one for your main data and one for your filtering. You can then check inside the table data source methods if you are in search mode or not, and return values from the appropriate fetched results controller. When called by the search display controller delegate method to start a search, change the predicate of the search fetched results controller, execute the fetch and and reload your search tableview. You should see the correct results.

Comment: Thanks! So in my last code block, instead of placing results in an array (`self.filteredList`) I need to implement another fetched results controller? Is that because then I can call its own `controllerDidChangeContent`?

Comment: That is another bonus yes. You probably have both your normal tableview and the search results tableview have the same data source - your view controller. So you need to differentiate in `cellForRow` and so on. You can ask `tableView == self.tableView` and determine this way which fetched results controller to query for data.

Comment: Thanks! Your direction worked. I also found this answer that gives some concrete examples on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471289/how-to-filter-nsfetchedresultscontroller-coredata-with-uisearchdisplaycontroll