# UICollectionViewController & UISearchBar not reloading data

Tags: ios, core-data, uisearchbar, nsfetchedresultscontroller

In my app, I have a CollectionViewController (PlayersCollectionView) that shows objects from a core data db.  I am trying to implement a UISearchBar to filter the collection view results. I load the collection view via segue from various other views and use predicates to filter the data so it shows only objects relevant to the view it was loaded from.  All this is working correctly.

I added a UISearchBar to the CollectionViewController and am trying to get it working.  When I tap the search button, I set a second predicate that should change the data. I call [self.collectionview reloadData] but this does not seem to actually reload the data...

Here is the relevant code:

```
@interface PlayersCollectionViewController ()
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSCompoundPredicate *compoundPredicate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSPredicate *searchPredicate;
@end

@implementation PlayersCollectionViewController
@synthesize titleText, predicate, noResultsMSG;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
...
//search bar...
UISearchBar *searchBar = [UISearchBar new];
searchBar.delegate = self;
searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
searchBar.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
searchBar.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDark;

self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar;

}


#pragma mark UISearchBarDelegate
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
[self applyFilters:[NSString stringWithString:searchBar.text]];
[searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)applyFilters:(NSString*)searchString {

_searchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName like[cd] %@", searchString];

**[self.collectionView reloadData];**
}

#pragma mark - Fetched Results Controller Section
-(NSFetchedResultsController*) fetchedResultsController
{
if (_fetchedResultsController !=nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchedRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entity =[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Player" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchedRequest setEntity:entity];
NSSortDescriptor *firsttNameSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *lastNameSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"lastName" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:firsttNameSortDescriptor,lastNameSortDescriptor, nil];
fetchedRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors;

NSString *sPred = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_searchPredicate];
if ([sPred length] > 0 ) {
    if (![sPred isEqualToString:@"(null)"]) {
        _compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[predicate, _searchPredicate]];
        fetchedRequest.predicate = _compoundPredicate;
    }
} else {
    fetchedRequest.predicate = predicate;
}

_fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchedRequest
                                                                managedObjectContext:context
                                                                  sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                           cacheName:nil];

_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

return _fetchedResultsController;

}
```

At run time, the applyFilters method is called and the _searchPredicate is set, but when I reloadData, nothing seems to happen...

Comment: Are you using a `UISearchDisplayController`?

Comment: No.  I was hoping to use the collection view...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes updating the UI is buggy when doing it in a thread other than the main thread. I'm not sure this is the problem here, but it's worth a try!

Try to run the `reloadData` message on the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the fetchedResultsController does not reconstruct itself when you call reloadData unless you kill it off first.

I fixed this by changing the way I build the predicate and using the searchBar delegate methods to kill it then reload...

In my fetchedResultsController...
    NSString *searchString = self.searchBar.text;
    if (searchString.length > 0) {
        NSPredicate *firstNameSearchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchString];
        NSPredicate *lastNameSearchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lastName CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchString];
        NSPredicate *orPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstNameSearchPredicate, lastNameSearchPredicate, nil]];

```
    NSPredicate *andPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:predicate, nil]];
    NSPredicate *finalPred = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:orPredicate, andPredicate, nil]];

    fetchedRequest.predicate = finalPred;
} else {
    fetchedRequest.predicate = predicate;
}
```

And the updated searcher delegate method...
    -(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
        self.fetchedResultsController = nil;

```
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController]performFetch:&error]) {
        abort();
    }

    [self.collectionView reloadData];
    [self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Thanks to Sergio's answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471289/how-to-filter-nsfetchedresultscontroller-coredata-with-uisearchdisplaycontroll) question...